# adding from the window object prompt

Tags: javascript, prompt, window-object

how do I use the window object, to add/sum two numbers, example of what I got so far - (I can add both numbers but can't get it to equal the sum?)

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script language="JavaScript">
    var requestMsg = "Enter a number";
    userInput1 = prompt(requestMsg);
    requestMsg = "Enter another number here";
    userInput2 = prompt(requestMsg);


    alert(total = " You entered " + userInput1 + " + " + userInput2 + " which equals ");
  </script>

  <head>

    <body>

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: what do you mean by `window object, to add/sum two numbers`?

Comment: You need to add both the variable like `const sum = Number(userInput1) + Number(userInput2);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue I guess you are facing is that when you add the inputs (eg: 3, 2) you get 32 instead of 5. This happens because the input retrieved by `prompt()` is a string and it needs to be converted/typecast into a number. You can do this by the `Number(input)` or `parseInt(input, "10")` functions.

`alert(total = " You entered " + userInput1 + " + " + userInput2 + " which equals " + (Number(userInput1) + Number(userInput2)));`

Answer (score 1):

You have to convert it to number because prompt returns a string, also I would recommend using [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings) like in the snippet below. 
With the template strings you can get rid of the string concatenations which allows you to write more readable code.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script language="JavaScript">
    var requestMsg = "Enter a number";
    userInput1 = prompt(requestMsg);
    requestMsg = "Enter another number here";
    userInput2 = prompt(requestMsg);


    alert(`You entered ${userInput1} ${userInput2} which equals ${Number(userInput1) + Number(userInput2)} `);
  </script>

  <head>

    <body>

    </body>

</html>
```